# I want to retrieve a list of videos from Youtube channel according to their ratings condition is = (likes/dislikes)>100

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I couldn't find solution.

I couldn't find solution from Youtube's v3 documentation.

Comment: Hi, what have you already tried?  Try to start from something, as the answer suggests, and then edit this post or ask another question

Answer (score 1):

The API does not have that functionality.

The only solution is to check the relevant data on the client end from an API response. Throw out the videos with the (likes/dislikes) < 100.